# The reason of the difficulties with .....were different values ...

Tags: grammar

I wonder whether it should be "was different values" or "were different values"? Should it refer to "the reason" or "different values?"

Comment: Can you provide the complete sentence. This is confusing.

Comment: The reason for the difficulties with grades were different values of exercises.

Comment: The verb 'was' belongs to the subject 'reason' which is singular.  Even if the reason was three causes, it's not "The reason were three causes."  "The reasons were three," however, also works.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason for the difficulties with grades was different values of exercises.

You need your verb(was) to agree with your subject(reason). Since reason is singular, was is correct.

This is subject-verb agreement. One common issue that crops up is when the subject is far away from the verb, and followed by something that is different from it in terms of number. This is called an error of proximity.